# How can I keep playing the UILocalNotification sound even if user press the other buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I use `UILocalNotification` for an alarm app, when it fires I want to keep the sound even if user press the other buttons like home button or sleep button. The [Rise app](http://www.simplebots.co/) just achieve that, any ideas how? Thanks.

Comment: Are Rise just playing a normal sound like a Music player app would do, so that the sound continues in the background? Forget `UILocalNotification` in this instance.

Comment: Hi James, the sound of Rise APP was played by schedule, so I'm pretty sure they're using UILocalNotification.

Comment: They may be using `UILocalNotification` to alert you, but at the same time playing the music, so it *looks* like the notification is still playing, but it's not.

Comment: @James, if they're playing the music, then it must be showed in control center, right? But it doesn't..

Comment: A similar answer to the one I've given can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16969363/394013). There doesn't seem to be a definitive answer as to how they do it.

Comment: @James, thank u, that's useful~  :)